# experience total not working by group function in collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, group

```
doctor_id | start_year | end_year
 2        | 2008       | 2012
 2        | 2012       | 2015
 5        | 2010       | 2013
 5        | 2013       | 2016
```

above is mysql  table `doctor_experience`

I have use this query but not working and throw unknown column 'count_year'  column error

```
    $exp_collection = Mage::getModel('doctor/experience')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*');
            $exp_collection ->getSelect()
            ->columns('(end_year-start_year) as count_year')
            ->columns('SUM(count_year) as total_experience')
            ->group('doctor_id');
print_r($exp_collection->getData());
```

I want a output  like below means I want to get total experience of doctor id

```
doctor_id | start_year | end_year | total_experience
 2        | 2008       | 2012     | 7
 5        | 2010       | 2013     | 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
   $exp_collection = Mage::getModel('doctor/experience')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*');
            $exp_collection ->getSelect()
            ->columns('(end_year-start_year) as count_year')
            ->columns('SUM(end_year-start_year) as total_experience')
            ->group('doctor_id');
```